# Prove the derivative of order 2 is discontinuous

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

> Let $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} y^2\ln\left(1+\dfrac{x^2}{y^2}\right)\text{
>  if }y\neq 0\\ 0\hspace{2.7cm}\text{  if }y=0.\end{cases}$$ Prove that
> $\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}$ and
> $\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}$ are discontinuous at
> $(0,0)$.

My attempt is to show $\lim\limits_{(a,b)\to (0,0)}\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}(a,b)\neq \dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}(0,0)$ and $\lim\limits_{(a,b)\to (0,0)}\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}(a,b)\neq \dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}(0,0).$
For $(a,b)$ that $b\neq 0$, I have $\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}(a,b)=\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}(a,b)=\dfrac{4a^3b}{(a^2+b^2)^2}$.

> Claim: $\lim\limits_{(a,b)\to (0,0)}\dfrac{4a^3b}{(a^2+b^2)^2}$ does not exists

To prove this claim, I choose $(a_n,b_n)=\left(\dfrac{1}{n},\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$ and $(a_n,b_n)=\left(0,\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$. (Both $b_n\neq 0$ and $(a_n,b_n)$ converges to $(0,0)$ as $n\to\infty$) .
Since $\lim\limits_{(a,b)\to (0,0)}\dfrac{4a^3b}{(a^2+b^2)^2}$ does not exists,$\lim\limits_{(a,b)\to (0,0)}\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}(a,b),\lim\limits_{(a,b)\to (0,0)}\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}(a,b)$ does not exist. Can I conclude $\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}$ and
$\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}$ are discontinuous at
$(0,0)$?

Comment: anyone.........?

Comment: A formal note: strictly speaking, if the derivative would be discontinuous in a certain point, then the derivative in that point does not exists. Hence you cannot refer to the mixed derivatives evaluated in (0,0). It should be ok  to play with the limits to show that you can get different values when computing them by approaching the accumulation point from different directions.